# Linq2Sql is not using identity cache for entities with composite primary key

Tags: c#, caching, linq-to-sql

do you know why Linq2Sql is not using identity cache for objects with composite PKs? By this msdn article (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd627203(v=vs.100).aspx) all requirements for using the cache are fulfilled.

Sample code:

```
using (var context = new OrderingDataContext())
{
            var o1 = context.Orders.SingleOrDefault(x => x.SiteId == 1 && x.OrderId == 1119);
            //cache will not be used - PK SiteId + OrderId
            var o2 = context.Orders.SingleOrDefault(x => x.SiteId == 1 && x.OrderId == 1119);

            var s1 = context.Sites.SingleOrDefault(x => x.SiteId == 1);
            //cache will be used - PK SiteId
            var s2 = context.Sites.SingleOrDefault(x => x.SiteId == 1);
}
```

Thanks
Veronika